# Input type not full width of td with bootstrap classes

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why the width of the input textbox on the 3rd column isnt spanning across the full width of the . I have set the width to px/% yet it still does not work. Here is a snippet of the code i have and how it is coming out.

[image: CSHTML CODE (C# MVC)]

[image: HTML View]

What i am wanting the outcome to be is for the input text in the 3rd column to span entirely across that td

Comment: Post your code in code blocks, not images.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you got that problem from the `width` you placed in the `td` and not in the entire column

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
   <colgroup>
     <col width=150px>
     <col width=150px>
     <col width=450px>
     <col width=170px>
   </colgroup>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td><label for="">1</label></td>
      <td><label for="">2</label></td>
      <td><label for="">3</label></td>
      <td><label for="">4</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="search" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

check this.